# Выборка из разгруженной связи многие-ко-многим

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеются три таблицы в бд из которых делается выборка:
[image: Таблички]

При следующем запросе

```
SELECT Zapis.Data AS Дата, Usluga.Nazvanie AS Услуга, Usluga.Stoimost AS Стоимость, Zapis.IDSostoyaniya
FROM Zapis 
INNER JOIN ON Zapis.IDZapisi = UslugaZapis.IDZapisi
INNER JOIN ON UslugaZapis.IDUslugi = Usluga.IDUslugi
```

Данные в выборке неверные, IDSostoyaniya в столбце одинаковое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в таблице Zapis

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит, такие данные в таблице. Чудес не бывает. Либо клиент чудит, отображая фигню. Либо Вы что-то перепутали или недосказали.

Comment: @Akina А что я мог перепутать и недосказать?  В таблице IDSostoyaniya разное

Comment: Да я-то откуда знаю. Просто чудес не бывает. Выполните тот же запрос из консольного клиента.

Comment: очевидно, такие данные в базе, к коду запроса вопросов быть не должно. если разве что вы хотели сделать какую то другую выборку, а сделали то, что сделали.

Comment: @teran хотел сделать именно такую выборку, но данные в таблице Zapis в столбце IDSostoyaniya другие, я сам в недоумении, пытался использовать другие запросы, но результат один и тот же

Comment: @Akina Консольный клиент дает те же результаты, прикреплю к посту содержание таблицы Zapis

Comment: А сделайте-ка сортировочку по IDZapisi, а?

Comment: @Akina Безрезультатно :(

Comment: я пока что все равно не вижу никакой проблемы. приведена часть данных. в начале пусть идут четверки. дальше то какие результаты показаны? не все же они 4, так? либо юзайте лефт джойны, на случай если в таблицах связей нет соответствий.

Comment: для обоих запросов сделайте сортировку по `idzapisi` и выложите результаты, как уже сказал @Akina

Comment: Ещё лучше - подготовьте адекватную модель на каком-нибудь fiddle, демонстрирующую проблему. По десятку записей в каждой таблице - достаточно. Ну и лишние поля поудалять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в неверном заполнении таблицы UslugaZapis
Программа, которая работала с базой данных заполняла таблицу UslugaZapis только тогда, когда у таблицы Zapis IDSostoyaniya было равно 4

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ подробностями, которые помогут другим в решении подобной проблемы.